# Not Receiving the detailed information about Trigger in Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am currently working with Google Apps Scripts in my project. I need complete info about the triggers created but not getting the specific info.

Scenario :

User 
- UserA

Logged in as UserA, created a google Spreadsheet and script to it. Also created few triggers. For e.g.

[Trigger Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6aUc6.png)

No I am trying to send trigger details through an email.

I am getting below info, which is not specific.

CLOCK  |  assignEditUrls  |  8953841127063344201  |  null  |  CLOCK
CLOCK  |  assignFormResponseIDs  |  2688484792317132442  |  null  |  CLOCK
CLOCK  |  processInputXML  |  3124957250420904432  |  null  |  CLOCK

For time driven triggers I am not getting the complete info, instead a keyword 'CLOCK'.

Is there any way to display the highlighted portions(please refer to the attachment) as well?

Below is my method:

```
function displayAllTriggers(triggerId) {
  var allTriggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  var trig = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < allTriggers.length; i++) {
    trig = trig + allTriggers[i].getEventType() + "  |  " + allTriggers[i].getHandlerFunction() + "  |  "+ allTriggers[i].getUniqueId() + "  |  " + allTriggers[i].getTriggerSourceId() + "  |  " + allTriggers[i].getTriggerSource()+ "\n";    
  }

  MailApp.sendEmail("UserA@gmail.com", "allTriggers", trig);
}
```

I tried searching but no luck. Please help.
Thanks in advance.